# ServerPilot for Django/Python applications?

Tags: database, python, web-server, server, django

I'm familiar with ServerPilot for PHP application management. I want to use a similar service to deploy a Django app that I've built.

Key features:

- App logging
- Server health monitoring
- Automatic SSL
- Database provisioning

Answer (score 2):

While ServerPilot is designed for PHP, it can be used for other languages, and you keep the benefits you're already familiar with.

https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-run-apps-in-any-language.html

https://gist.github.com/rubenrubiob/f9f8d42d79be3f3ab1791c7a11482149

Comment: How does it work for the "key features" in the question?